# Drawing grid with random color in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a 10x10 grid in TikZ like so:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \foreach \y in {0.05,0.15,...,0.95}
    \foreach \x in {0.05,0.15,...,0.95}
        \pgfmathparse{0.9*rnd+0.3}
        \definecolor{MyColor}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathresult}
        \node[fill=MyColor,minimum size=0.1] at (\x,\y) {}; 
    \draw[step=.1,help lines] (0,0) grid (1,1); 
    \draw[->] (0,1) -- (1.2,1);
    \draw[->] (0,1) -- (0,-0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which is already quite close to what I had in mind, but the nodes don't line up properly. What am I doing wrong? Here is an image of my output:

[image: My Attempt].

Also, since I'm new to TikZ, feel free to comment on the code, in terms of readability, coding practices and so on.

Comment: Nicely done! It will align if you just add the missing options `minimum size=1mm,inner sep=0,outer sep=0` instead of `minimum size=0.1`. Also it is useful to write up `grid (1cm,1cm)` so you can keep track of the units :)

Comment: @percusse Thanks, that works. However, if I want to change scale=1 to scale=2, I also have to adjust minimum size. Is there a way to make it independent? As for the units in grid, why is that preferable? Like a math plot, it don't think of it in cm, so it would be counterintuitive to supply it, no?

Comment: You can add the option `transform shape` to the `tikzpicture` environment. That will enlarge everything together. Regarding the `cm` thing, it is just a matter of taste probably. Nevermind that :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should not always use the `node` feature. Sometimes you need the coordinates of the node, if you don't it can often pay to do it "manually" (less code).

I have here compiled 2 methods, one where yours is corrected, and the other without the use of `nodes`. I prefer the one without nodes as it is more drawing clean, but everyone can prefer whatever style they want!

#### Without `node`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \foreach \y in {0.0,0.1,...,0.9} {
      \foreach \x in {0.0,0.1,...,0.9} {
          \pgfmathparse{0.9*rnd+0.3}
          \definecolor{MyColor}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathresult}
          \path[fill=MyColor] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(0.1,0.1); 
      }
  }
  \draw[step=.1,help lines] (0,0) grid (1,1); 
  \draw[->] (0,1) -- (1.2,1);
  \draw[->] (0,1) -- (0,-0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As you can see you just draw a rectangle and fill it with the color of your choice.

#### Fixed code

What you need to ensure is correct placement, and correct size. A `node` usually has some space associated with the filling of the text. This space is to ensure not too tight a drawing compared to the text, compare the following two `tikz` drawings:

```
\tikz \node[draw,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] {H};
\tikz \node[draw] {H};
```

Therefore i have added that you do not want any `outer sep`, but kept an `inner sep` which has the size of your node. 
Next is your ability to place the `node` with respect to its size. Here `anchor` is your friend, it basically tells if the node should be placed at the coordinate anchoring the node at the coordinate within the node. Try for instance and change `anchor=center` to `anchor=east`. With `anchor=center` it takes the center coordinate in the node and place at the coordinate you specify. With `anchor=east` it takes the east point of the node and places at the coordinate.
It is strictly not needed in the below example, but gives a good idea what it does (and it is **VERY** useful)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \foreach \y in {0.1,0.2,...,.9} {
      \foreach \x in {0.1,0.2,...,.9} {
          \pgfmathparse{0.9*rnd+0.3}
          \definecolor{MyColor}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathresult}
          \node[fill=MyColor,inner sep=0.1cm,outer sep=0pt,anchor=center] at (\x,\y) {}; 
      }
  }
  \draw[step=.1,help lines] (0,0) grid (1,1); 
  \draw[->] (0,1) -- (1.2,1);
  \draw[->] (0,1) -- (0,-0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Hope this brings you in the correct direction.

#### Colors in `tikz`

Also when defining new colors you can skip a define color step:

```
\pgfmathparse{70*rnd+30}
\edef\tmp{\pgfmathresult}
\node[fill=white!\tmp!black] ...
```

In this case you skip the `\definecolor`, and need not worry about that. In this case the number should be between 0 and 100.
Further more you need the `\edef` step to keep that result. There is a lot of math going on in `tikz` so you need to save the math variable temporarily (which is why `\edef` is needed.)

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for. I'm using your version without the nodes, I just didn't know better. Note: I had to change 0.9 to 1 in the foreach to fill all the rectangles.

Comment: @Psirus i am glad, sorry, missed that one :)
Please see the edited answer where a hint of the color is added.

Comment: @zeroth you can remove`anchor= center`, by default it is always used and `outer sep=0pt` can be also removed because this option changes only the position of the anchors and not the size of the node.

Comment: @Altermundus i know, i simply added them for descriptive purposes, i also noted in my answer that `anchor=center` is not needed.

Comment: Old thread! Regarding the "Colors in tikz", what if I want random colors instead of grey levels. Do I have to define three random variables or can I reuse one (re-randomizing it for each of the R, G, B, for instance)?

Comment: No, you really need 3 different random numbers. :)