# Draw striped arrowhead in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to draw an arrow with a striped arrowhead using tikz.  I can't find anything in the [tikz docs](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows) to do this.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,font=\sffamily\Large]
\draw[-{Latex[length=30mm,angle'=10]}] (0,-2) -- (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to make something like the below figure.  Black line with arrowhead that has evenly spaced orange/white stripes:

[image: arrowhead]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `inset` is misused, it denoted the number of stripes (including the white/transparent ones).
An even number will lead to the line ending at a white stripe.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name = Striped Triangle,
  defaults = {
    length  = +3pt 4.5 .8,
    width'  = +0pt .75,
    inset'  = +13pt,
    angle=+60:+2.7pt +3.6,
  },
  setup code={%
    \pgfarrowssettipend{0pt}%
    \pgfarrowssetbackend{-\pgfarrowlength}%
    \pgfarrowssetlineend{\dimexpr-\pgfarrowlength+.001pt}% visual things
    \pgfarrowsupperhullpoint{0pt}{0pt}%
    \pgfarrowsupperhullpoint{-\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowwidth}%
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowwidth
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowinset
    \pgfmathreciprocal{\pgfarrowinset}%
    \let\pgfarrowstripedtrianglefrac\pgfmathresult
    \pgfarrowssave\pgfarrowstripedtrianglefrac
  },
  drawing code={%
    \pgfmathloop % could use qicker \pgfmathmultiply@ here
      \pgfmathmultiply{\pgfmathcounter-1}{\pgfarrowstripedtrianglefrac}\let\near\pgfmathresult
      \ifdim\pgfmathcounter pt=\pgfarrowinset \def\far{1}% just use 1 instead of n*1/n
      \else
        \pgfmathmultiply{\pgfmathcounter}{\pgfarrowstripedtrianglefrac}\let\far\pgfmathresult
      \fi
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpointscale{\near}{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfarrowlength}{+.5\pgfarrowwidth}}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointscale{\far }{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfarrowlength}{+.5\pgfarrowwidth}}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointscale{\far }{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowwidth}}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointscale{\near}{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowwidth}}}%
      \pgfpathclose
      \ifdim\pgfinteval{1+\pgfmathcounter}pt<\pgfarrowinset\relax
      \edef\pgfmathcounter{\pgfinteval{\pgfmathcounter+1}}%
    \repeatpgfmathloop
    \pgfusepathqfill
  },
  parameters={\the\pgfarrowlength,\the\pgfarrowwidth,\the\pgfarrowinset}
}
\tikzset{>={Striped Triangle[fill=orange, angle'=30]}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
\foreach[count=\i] \ang in {0, 30, ..., 359}
  \draw[-{>[inset=2*\i-1]}] (0,0) -- (\ang:.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[count=\i] \bendmode in {quick, flex, bend}{
\tikzset{yshift=-\i cm}
\draw [red!25,line width=1mm] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw [red,line width=1mm,-{[\bendmode]>.>>}]
  (-1,-.5) node[right, black] {\bendmode}
  .. controls (0,-.5) and (0,0) .. (1,0);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: star]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Here is an option using decorations.markings, although they can be improved to adapt to curves, in this case it does not, but you can look for examples with [coils](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449744/154390), however it is best to declare it as a style or pic so that you can do a lot with little code.

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings,calc}
\definecolor{brown}{HTML}{2E2111}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Environment Styles
        MyArrow/.style={
            draw,
            shorten >=28pt,
            line width=2pt,
            preaction={
                decorate,
                shorten >=0pt,
                line width=1pt,
                rounded corners=0,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=at position 1
                    with {
                        \clip[](0,0) -- ++(-28pt,-5pt) -- ++(0,10pt) -- cycle;
                        \fill[#1](0,0) -- ++(-28pt,-5pt) -- ++(0,10pt) -- cycle;
                        \foreach \k in {1,...,6}{\draw[white, line width=2pt] (-4pt*\k,-5pt) -- ++(0,10pt);}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
        \foreach \i in {0,45,...,315} {\draw[MyArrow=orange] (0,0) -- ++(\i:2);}
        \foreach \i in {0,45,...,315} {\draw[MyArrow=blue, rounded corners] (4,0) --++(\i:1) -- ++(45+\i:2);}
        \draw[MyArrow=red](0,0) [out=-15,in=180] to ++(4,-3)[out=0,in=180] -- ++(2,0);
        \foreach \distance in {0,1,...,40}{
            \pgfmathparse{0.9*rnd+0.3}
            \definecolor{Rcolor}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathresult} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37279/154390
            \draw[MyArrow=green!50!Rcolor,brown!50!Rcolor] (-1.7,-6)++(\distance*0.22,0) -- ++(0,2+0.7*rand*rand););
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat kludgy. It would be easier to simply draw the shape, but if you especially want an arrow tip:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/702116/
% cwestiwn Medulla Oblongata: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/702111/
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,font=\sffamily\Large]
  \draw[-{Latex[length=30mm,angle'=10]},line width=0pt,postaction={draw,-,shorten >=30mm-1.2pt,black,very thick},white,pattern={Lines[line width=2.5pt,distance=5pt]},pattern color=orange] (0,-2) -- (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: orange-striped tip on black line]

If it doesn't have to be an arrow tip, you can simply fill a triangular path. This doesn't rely on the background being white.

[image: orange-striped arrow and orange-striped triangle on black lines]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/702116/
% cwestiwn Medulla Oblongata: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/702111/
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,font=\sffamily\Large]
  \draw[-{Latex[length=30mm,angle'=10]},line width=0pt,postaction={draw,-,shorten >=30mm-1.2pt,black,very thick},white,pattern={Lines[line width=2.5pt,distance=5pt]},pattern color=orange] (0,-2) -- (0,3);
  \begin{scope}[xshift=10mm]
    \draw[shorten >=30mm-1.2pt,black,very thick] (0,-2) -- (0,3);
    \path [pattern color=orange,pattern={Lines[line width=2.5pt,distance=5pt]}] (-.5,0) -- (0,3) -- (.5,0) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks @cfr, I want to use this arrow as part of a bigger figure which requires me to rotate the arrows. I can rotate the arrows but the stripes are always horizontal eg. `\draw[-{Latex[length=30mm,angle'=10]},line width=0pt,postaction={draw,-,shorten >=30mm-1.2pt,black,very thick},white,pattern={Lines[line width=2.5pt,distance=5pt]},pattern color=orange] (0,-2) -- (1,2.8);`. Is there a way to rotate the arrowhead AND stripes?

Comment: @MedullaOblongata You didn't mention that in the question. As it happens, these patterns are designed to be rotatable. So that bit's just a matter of adding `angle=<value>` in the appropriate place. However, I'm not sure how you're rotating the arrows (or what you mean by rotating the arrows), so I don't know whether that will work in your case or how to figure out whether it will.

Comment: @MedullaOblongata If I draw the path at an angle, the pattern rotates, too. If I put the arrow on a curve and use `bend`, it also works fine (though the black line does less well). So presumably you're rotating them in some other way, but you don't say what.